# :checked в firefox? почему не работает?

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox

использовался вот этот способ: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144104/
во всех браузерах все нормально, кроме firexox, он не реаигрует на свойство checked. вроде бы этот псевдо-класс должен работать в современных браузерах?

Comment: [Минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) проблемы должен быть в самом вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox [сохраняет данные при перезагрузке страницы](https://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/664974).

Попробуйте добавить атрибут `autocomplete="off"`.